# Unable to install face_recognition in python3

Tags: python-3.8

The version of python I'm using is 3.7.0. Tried it with 3.8 but ended in same error
I installed the latest version of cmake and tried installing face_recognition[image] but I'm getting the following error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the error is due to trying to install it in windows. It works on windows after following some steps

These steps can be found here if you wish to install it on windows 10

https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508

Otherwise it works perfectly fine on ubuntu or Mac OS